# Where can I find the source for THREE.SVGObject?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm reading through the threejs source trying to figure out how it uses the SVG modules to draw shapes onscreen.  There are several places I've found where a call to THREE.SVGObject is made:

https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/loaders/SVGLoader

```
scene.add( new THREE.SVGObject(doc) );
```

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/svg_sandbox.html

```
line 161:
var object = new THREE.SVGObject( node.cloneNode() );
```

I'm trying to find this SVGObject so that I can read its source, but I can't find it anywhere.  I've even cloned the Threejs project and searched through that.  Does anyone know how I can find it?

Comment: I found it by using GitHub's search function... https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/2dc7006d75da49bd44a36fb369daf5370859851c/examples/js/renderers/SVGRenderer.js#L5

Comment: Do note that asking to find code for you is explicitly off-topic on Stack Overflow, however.